# Find the largest prime factor of $1+f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\dots+f(30)$ where $f(n)=n\cdot n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, factorial, telescopic-series

Here's my approach:
express the sum as a telescoping series
although I am not sure how to go about it I am sure it is either 29 or 31. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that 
$$n\cdot n! = (n +1 - 1)n! = (n + 1)! - n!.$$